# how object return in function in c++?

Tags: c++, object, return-value

```
#include<queue>
using namespace std;

class node {
    public:
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    // node(){}
    node(int d) {
        this -> data = d;
         this -> left = NULL;
         this -> right = NULL;
    }
  
};
node buildTree() {
     cout << "Enter the data: " << endl;
     int data = 2;
    //  cin >> data;
     node r(data);
     node left(4);
    cout<<&r<<endl;
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"print";
    node root = buildTree();
    cout<<&root<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

in c++ why local variable address r and main function variable root address are same?

and when i comment left and right data member of node class then it print different!why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QbQZ.png)

it is output of  example why local object (r) of buildtree function and main function object root  address are same

it should be different.

Comment: Named return value optimization is being implemented here.  That optimization allows `buildTree` to directly initialize `root` and avoid making a copy.

Comment: Read [C++ copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (specially _NRVO_, which is happening in your case). If you are using `g++` or `clang++` compiler, compile your program with `-fno-elide-constructors` option and run and check output.

Comment: can anyone explain me how it works?

Comment: The root variable in main and the r variable in buildTree never exist at the same time, so their memory is reused.

Comment: no, its becuse of NRVO in c++